# How to return a variable multiple times and create an array

Tags: python, arrays

I am creating a shop/inventory system for a python rpg and return several variables from a function in my shop. I create 3-5 items every time the shop is visited so right now if you print one of my returned variables it will print the info from the last item created. I need to be able to store each unique items values in an array so that each item can be called on not just the last one.

```
if plus == 0: #if item made has a plus equal to nothing
                        if has_add == 'yes': #if it has an add
                            if item_type == 'weapon':  #if it is a weapon (no plus, has add, is weapon)   
                                created_item = print(str(count) + ". " + quality + " " + wep_adj + " " + "" + weapon_type + " of " + wep_add + "..........Attack: " + str(weapon_attack) + " Price: " + str(wep_price)) #print this
                            if item_type == 'armor': #if it is an armor (no plus, has add, is armor)
                                created_item = print(str(count) + ". " + quality + " " + arm_adj + " " + " " + armor_piece + " of " + arm_add + "..........Armor: " + str(armor_defense) + " HP: " + str(armor_hp) + " Price: " + str(arm_price)) #print this
                        else: # if item doesnt have add
                            if item_type == 'weapon':  #if it is a weapon (no plus, no add, is weapon)
                                created_item = print(str(count) + ". " + quality + " " + wep_adj + " " + "" + weapon_type + "..........Attack: " + str(weapon_attack) + " Price: " + str(wep_price)) #print this
                            if item_type == 'armor': # if it is an armor (no plus, no add, is armor)
                                created_item = print(str(count) + ". " + quality + " " + arm_adj + " " + " " + armor_piece  + "..........Armor: " + str(armor_defense) + " HP: " + str(armor_hp) + " Price: " + str(arm_price)) #print this
                    else: #if item made has a plus 
                        if has_add == 'yes': # if it has an add
                            if item_type == 'weapon': # if it is a weapon (has plus, has add, is weapon)
                                created_item = print(str(count) + ". " + quality + " " + wep_adj + " " + "" + weapon_type + " of " + wep_add + " +" + str(plus) + "..........Attack: " + str(weapon_attack) + " Price: " + str(wep_price)) #print this
                            if item_type == 'armor': #if it is an armor (has plus, has add, is armor)
                                created_item = print(str(count) + ". " + quality + " " + arm_adj + " " + " " + armor_piece + " of " + arm_add + " +" + str(plus)  + "..........Armor: " + str(armor_defense) + " HP: " + str(armor_hp) + " Price: " + str(arm_price)) #print this
                        else: # if it doesnt have an add
                            if item_type == 'weapon': #if it is a weapon (has plus, no add, is weapon)
                                created_item = print(str(count) + ". " + quality + " " + wep_adj + " " + "" + weapon_type + " +" +  str(plus) + "..........Attack: " + str(weapon_attack) + " Price: " + str(wep_price)) #print this
                            if item_type == 'armor': #if it is an armor (has plus, no add, is armor)
                                created_item = print(str(count) + ". " + quality + " " + arm_adj + " " + " " + armor_piece + " +" + str(plus)  + "..........Armor: " + str(armor_defense) + " HP: " + str(armor_hp) + " Price: " + str(arm_price)) #print this

                    if item_type == 'weapon': #allows us to get info out of function
                        return (created_item, count, quality, wep_adj, weapon_type, wep_add, plus, weapon_attack, wep_price, randvar)
                    else:
                        return (created_item, count, quality, arm_adj, armor_piece, arm_add, plus, armor_defense, arm_price, armor_hp)



                while items_amount > items_made: #if we've made 3-5 items, stop making them
                    new_item, count, quality, adj, piece, add, plus, stat, price, other_stat = make_item()
                    items_made += 1 #increase items made every time one is made
                    count += 1
                return (new_item, count, quality, adj, piece, add, plus, stat, price, other_stat)      



            new_item, count, quality, adj, piece, add, plus, stat, price, other_stat = generate_items() #call function to make all items when shop is visited
            print(new_item, count, quality, adj, piece, add, plus, stat, price, other_stat)
```

Since my code is so immense I don't want to link the entirety of relevant code. The most relevant is this:

```
while items_amount > items_made: #if we've made 3-5 items, stop making them
                    new_item, count, quality, adj, piece, add, plus, stat, price, other_stat = make_item()
                    items_made += 1 #increase items made every time one is made
                    count += 1
                return (new_item, count, quality, adj, piece, add, plus, stat, price, other_stat)
```

I need to be able to return them as arrays instead of variables

Comment: What you are doing already return a tuple containg the variables new_item, count, quality, adj, piece, add, plus, stat, price, other_stat

Comment: @user312016 yes but I need each variable in the tuple to be stored seperately for each item created. Right now each item created overwrites the last.

Comment: @Shnipper You may use a dictionnary instead though. What are you meaning by "Right now each item created overwrites the last" ?

Comment: @user312016 the function is called between 3-5 times. Every time the function is called a new item is created. In my last line of the first code above I print every variable that is returned. What gets printed is the information for the last item that was created. I need a way to access the information for the other items that were made before that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your tuples into a list:

```
items = list()
while items_amount > items_made:  # if we've made 3-5 items, stop making them
    new_item, count, quality, adj, piece, add, plus, stat, price, other_stat = make_item()
    items_made += 1  # increase items made every time one is made
    count += 1
    items.append((new_item, count, quality, adj, piece, add, plus, stat, price, other_stat))

return items
```

Comment: TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (10 given)

Comment: @Shniper I fixed a typo.

Comment: This works but how do I access each individual value. So if I wanted to access the adj of the 2nd item how would I? I tried items.adj[1], didn't work

Comment: You mean you added extra parenthesis to make the appended type a tuple.

Comment: @Shniper You would have to do items[1][3]

Comment: If you want to be able to manipipulate the data after it is returned you should use append([...]) instead of append((...))

Answer (score 2):

You could treat whatever you are returning as one `tuple` variable and append it to a `list`:

```
items = list()
while items_amount > items_made:  # if we've made 3-5 items, stop making them
    new_item_details = make_item() # assign to one tuple variable
    items.append(new_item_details) # append to list
    items_made += 1  # increase items made every time one is made
    count += 1
return items
```

If you want to access each details of individual `item` and you want it to be nice as well, I suggest you create a class with required variables:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, item_details):
        self.item = item_details[0]
        self.count = item_details[1]
        self.quality = item_details[2]
        self.adj = item_details[3]

        ... # similarily other fields

        self.other_stat = item_details[9]
```

and then you can create these items:

```
items = list()
while items_amount > items_made:  # if we've made 3-5 items, stop making them
    new_item_details = make_item() # assign to one tuple variable
    items.append(Item(new_item_details)) # append to list
    items_made += 1  # increase items made every time one is made
    count += 1
return items
```

Now, if you want to access `adj` of 2nd item:

```
# 1st index would be the second item in the list 
items[1].adj # access using variable name on the instance
```